# Nested bloc bloc depends on bloc to build

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm currently bringing myself up to speed on bloc architecture working with open api

1.https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums and 2.https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/albumId

i.e photos/albumId depends on albums response

albums response

```
 [
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "quidem molestiae enim"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "title": "omnis laborum odio"
    },
]
```

photos response with id gotten from albums i.e photos/albumId=1

```
 [
    {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
    },
    {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796"
    },
    {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "title": "officia porro iure quia iusto qui ipsa ut modi",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/24f355",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355"
    },
    {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 4,
        "title": "culpa odio esse rerum omnis laboriosam voluptate repudiandae",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/d32776",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/d32776"
    },
    {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 5,
        "title": "natus nisi omnis corporis facere molestiae rerum in",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/f66b97",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/f66b97"
    },
    {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 6,
        "title": "accusamus ea aliquid et amet sequi nemo",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/56a8c2",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/56a8c2"
    },
]
```

I have been able to implement this but what seems to be the problem now is I'm trying to
generate widget based on what i'm trying to do

**what i'm trying to achieve**
[image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AgNIVO2aWV_ZCvSRGLUEdkvZoTT_IQ-0/view?usp=sharing)

** the problem **
(image)(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LU_bwCooDT6Tgx-DpDNAFGDrwStkn2Gq/view?usp=sharing)

[image: source]

**BLOC ALBUMS**

```
class AlbumsBloc extends Bloc<AlbumsEvent, AlbumsState> {
  final AlbumsRepository albumsRepository;

  AlbumsBloc(this.albumsRepository) : super(AlbumsLoadingState()) {
    on<AlbumsEvent>((event, emit) async {
      if (event is LoadAlbumsEvent || event is RefreshAlbumsEvent) {
        emit(AlbumsLoadingState());
        try {
          final albums = await albumsRepository.fetchAlbumsData();
          emit(AlbumsLoadedState(albums: albums));
        } catch (e) {
          emit(AlbumsErrorState(error: e.toString()));
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```
abstract class AlbumsEvent extends Equatable {
  const AlbumsEvent();
}

class LoadAlbumsEvent extends AlbumsEvent {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class RefreshAlbumsEvent extends AlbumsEvent {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

```
abstract class AlbumsState extends Equatable {
  const AlbumsState();
}

class AlbumsEmptyState extends AlbumsState {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class AlbumsLoadingState extends AlbumsState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AlbumsLoadedState extends AlbumsState {
  final List<Albums> albums;

  const AlbumsLoadedState({required this.albums});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [albums];
}

class AlbumsErrorState extends AlbumsState {
  final String error;

  const AlbumsErrorState({required this.error});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}
```

**BLOC PHOTOS**

```
class PhotosBloc extends Bloc<PhotosEvent, PhotosState> {
  final PhotosRepository photosRepository;

  PhotosBloc(this.photosRepository) : super(PhotosLoadingState()) {
    on<PhotosEvent>((event, emit) async {
      if (event is LoadPhotosEvent) {
        emit(PhotosLoadingState());
        try {
          final photos = await photosRepository.fetchPhotosData(event.albumId);
          emit(PhotosLoadedState(photos: photos));
        } catch (e) {
          emit(PhotosErrorState(error: e.toString()));
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```
abstract class PhotosEvent extends Equatable {
  const PhotosEvent();
}

class LoadPhotosEvent extends PhotosEvent {
  final int albumId;

  const LoadPhotosEvent({required this.albumId});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [albumId];
}
```

```
abstract class PhotosState extends Equatable {
  const PhotosState();
}

class PhotosEmpty extends PhotosState {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class PhotosLoadingState extends PhotosState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class PhotosLoadedState extends PhotosState {
  final List<Photos> photos;

  const PhotosLoadedState({required this.photos});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [photos];
}

class PhotosErrorState extends PhotosState {
  final String error;

  const PhotosErrorState({required this.error});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [error];
}
```

**THE CODE**

```
class AlbumScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AlbumScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return AlbumScreenState();
  }
}

class AlbumScreenState extends State<AlbumScreen> {

  final PhotosRepository photosRepository = PhotosRepository();

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    BlocProvider.of<AlbumsBloc>(context).add(LoadAlbumsEvent());
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final photoBloc = BlocProvider.of<PhotosBloc>(context);
    return  Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(60.0),
          child: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 0,
            title: const Text("", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0),),
          ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: BlocBuilder<AlbumsBloc,AlbumsState>(
            builder: (context,state){
              if( state is AlbumsLoadingState){
                return  const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              if(state is AlbumsLoadedState){
                  return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children:   [
                    for(int i = 0; i < state.albums.length; i++)
                    BlocBuilder <PhotosBloc,PhotosState>(
                      bloc:  BlocProvider.of<PhotosBloc>(context)..add(LoadPhotosEvent(albumId: i)),
                      builder: (context,state){
                        if( state is PhotosLoadingState){
                          return  const Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        }
                        if(state is PhotosLoadedState){
                          final photos = state.photos;
                          return AlbumsWithAlbumCard(
                            albumIndex: i,
                            photos: photos,
                          );
                        }
                        return Container();
                      }
                    )
                  ],
                );
              }
              return Container();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this small restructure:

```dart
class AlbumScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AlbumScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => AlbumsBloc()..add(LoadAlbumsEvent()),
      child: AlbumView(),
    );
  }
}

class AlbumView extends StatelessWidget {
   AlbumView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final PhotosRepository photosRepository = PhotosRepository();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(60.0),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
          title: const Text(
            "",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: BlocBuilder<AlbumsBloc, AlbumsState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is AlbumsLoadingState) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              if (state is AlbumsLoadedState) {
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: state.albums.map((album) {
                    BlocListener<AlbumBloc, AlbumState>(
                      listenWhen: (previous, current) => previous != current,
                      listener: (context, state) {
                        if(state is AlbumsLoadedState) {
                          context.read<PhotosBloc>().add(LoadPhotosEvent(albumId: album.id));
                        }
                      },
                      child: BlocBuilder<PhotosBloc, PhotosState>(
                        builder: (context, state) {
                          if( state is PhotosLoadingState){
                            return  const Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            );
                          }
                          if(state is PhotosLoadedState){
                            final photos = state.photos;
                            return AlbumsWithAlbumCard(
                              albumIndex: album.id,
                              photos: photos,
                            );
                          }
                          return Container();
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  }).toList(),
                );
              }
              return Container();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is in different ways, but based on the UI you add

Comment: okay, I'm listening

Comment: The ```PhotosRepository``` should be inside your bloc class and load it through dependency injection or use RepositoryProvider

Comment: that is what i did, all bloc state and event, have been implemented you can see I'm getting that through LoadPhotosEvent

Comment: can you paste the code as well

Comment: if that is what you did ```PhotosRepository photosRepository = PhotosRepository();``` is not need there

Comment: yes i'm not using it at any point

Comment: the code you shared up here is the same as what i did up there just a different approach. if you check what i achieved already you can see that it's has been done what seems to be the issue now is, for  each album it should load it's images and title that's what i'm trying to achieve now

Comment: check the update if it works

Comment: it's doesn't work i have also tried this approach

Comment: can you do this push it on github and share the link

Comment: here is it - https://github.com/yinkyAde/cypress_album.git

Comment: you can check the pull request

Comment: i will check now. Thnak you.